# Updating a variable in a procedure called multiple tmies

Tags: postscript

I'm trying to generate a postscript "bitmap" by making repeated calls to a block-drawing procedure.

Rather than define the position of the block on each call, I'd like the procedure to update the starting position automatically, based on a known block size of (say) 100 pixels, something like this:

```
% starting position
/px { 72 } def
/py { 720 } def

% block-drawing procedure, input= r-g-b
/block {
    setrgbcolor
    px py moveto
    0 100 rlineto
    100 0 rlineto
    0 100 neg rlineto
    fill
    % NOW ADJUST PX AND PY BY 100 AND -100, AHEAD OF NEXT CALL 
} def

% draw three increasingly lighter boxes, automatically shifted 
0 0 0 box 
.25 .25 .25 box
.5 .5 .5 box
% etc...
```

Is there a simple way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, alter the values of px and py.

Note that your code defines px and py as executable arrays, which, when executed, leave a value on the operand stack. There is no need to do that, this:

```
/px 72 def
/py 720 def
```

works just as well.

I think you are missing the fact that '`def`' associates a key and a value in the current dictionary. Since you haven't started a new dictionary, you get the default one, which is `userdict`. If you use '`def`' again, then it associates a new value with the same key in the dictionary.

So if you do:

```
% starting position
/px 72 def
/py 720 def

% block-drawing procedure, input= r-g-b
/block {
    setrgbcolor
    px py moveto
    0 100 rlineto
    100 0 rlineto
    0 100 neg rlineto
    fill
    % NOW ADJUST PX AND PY BY 100 AND -100, AHEAD OF NEXT CALL 
    px 100 add /px exch def
    py 100 sub /py exch def
} def

% draw three increasingly lighter boxes, automatically shifted 
0 0 0 box 
.25 .25 .25 box
.5 .5 .5 box
% etc...
```

That will do what you seem to want.

Comment: It worked, thank-you! Having that prototype to work from has saved me an enormous amount of time!

Answer (score 1):

Ken has answered your question about making and using definitions, but I'd like to show a different way of doing this which is perhaps more natural to postscript.

If you want to have drawing procedures which automatically position themselves, you can treat each procedure like a glyph in a font. By this I mean that you use the `currentpoint` in the graphics state as your *variable*. It holds both coordinates together nicely. Each drawing procedure then executes `rmoveto` to position the point for the next proc.

So here's how I would go about writing your block-drawing proc:

```
72 720  % starting position

% r g b  block  -    [expects currentpoint and adjusts currentpoint]
% draws a block
/block {
    setrgbcolor
    0 100 rlineto
    100 0 rlineto
    0 100 neg rlineto
    closepath
    currentpoint fill moveto
    % NOW ADJUST PX AND PY BY 100 AND -100, AHEAD OF NEXT CALL 
    100 -100 rmoveto
} def

% draw three increasingly lighter boxes, automatically shifted 
moveto  % starting position from above
0 0 0 block
.25 .25 .25 block
.5 .5 .5 block
```

Since `fill` destroys the path, we have to sandwich it with `currentpoint` ... `moveto` to preserve the point.

Also, take a look at how we can tease-out a new parameter for the length of a side *without making a new definition*. The idea is we can arrange data on the stack and then call all the operators upon it. So if the argument is `100`, we just need to make the stack look like `0 -100 100 0 0 100` then call `rlineto rlineto rlineto` or even `3{rlineto}repeat`. Remember all data goes onto the stack, and is then available *top-down*.

So build up the data *in reverse*, then execute the operators straight.

```
0 -100
     100 0
          0 100
          rlineto
     rlineto
rlineto
```

Building up the data is just simple stack manipulation and arithmetic.

```
72 720  % starting position

% N r g b  block  -    [expects currentpoint and adjusts currentpoint]
% draws a block colored (r,g,b) of side-length N
/block {
    setrgbcolor  % N
    0 exch dup neg exch 0 0 2 index % 0 -N  N 0  0 N
    3 {rlineto} repeat
    closepath
    currentpoint fill moveto
    % NOW ADJUST PX AND PY BY 100 AND -100, AHEAD OF NEXT CALL 
    100 -100 rmoveto
} def

% draw three increasingly lighter boxes, automatically shifted 
moveto  % starting position from above
0 0 0 block
.25 .25 .25 block
.5 .5 .5 block
```